# Finding subranges in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find all sub ranges within a column to produce year ranges and apply those to the specific value. Here is the code I'm using to generate the dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    years = {'year':[1991, 1990, 1992, 1994, 1996, 1997, 1999]}
    
    df6 = pd.DataFrame(years)
    
    df6['year_max'] = ''
    df6['year_min'] = ''
    df6['year_min'] = pd.to_numeric(df6['year_min'])
    df6['year_max'] = pd.to_numeric(df6['year_max'])
    
    print(df6)
```

The goal dataframe:
[goal dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1QOB.png)

```
    goal_years = {'year':[1991, 1990, 1992, 1994, 1996, 1997, 1999], 'year_max':[1992, 1992, 1992, 1994, 1997, 1997, 1999], 'year_min':[1990, 1990, 1990, 1994, 1996, 1996, 1999]}
    
    goal_df = pd.DataFrame(goal_years)
```

What I've tried:

```
    df6 = df6.sort_values(by=['year'], ignore_index=True)
    j=0
    for i, r in df6.iterrows():
        counter = 0;
        start_year = df6.year.iloc[i]
        end_year = start_year
        #print(start_year)
        while(df6.year.iloc[j + 1] - df6.year.iloc[j]==1):
            end_year = df6.year.iloc[j + 1]
            counter += 1
            j += 1
            #print(end_year, i, j, counter)
        if(counter==0 and pd.isnull(df6.at[i,'year_max'])):
            df6.year_max.iloc[i] = end_year
            df6.year_min.iloc[i] = start_year
        elif(counter!=0):
            for idx in range(counter + 1):
                df6.year_max.iloc[idx + i] = end_year
                df6.year_min.iloc[idx + i] = start_year
                #print(idx + i)
```

this outputs: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rocs9.png)
My hunch is that my j index is in the wrong place, but if I try to set j=i I get index out of bound error.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite sure what you mean? I provided the original df as well as how I'm iterating over it. The only screenshots I posted were the output and the what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I added a dataframe that is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My issue was 2 fold. One I was updating the start year for every iteration, which was setting the start year to min year for every iteration. I only needed a new start year for the start of a new range. To alleviate this I do a check to see if the year has already been assigned.

Secondly, my j counter was not in the correct position. Every iteration I needed it to start from i. I did this by setting j=i however this threw and out boundes, so I need to check to make sure j was never more than 1 minus the total values in the temp dataframe.

```
df6 = df6.sort_values(by=['year'], ignore_index=True)
j=0
for i, r in df6.iterrows():
    counter = 0;
    if(pd.isnull(df6.at[i,'year_max'])):
        start_year = df6.year.iloc[i]
    end_year = start_year
    #print("--------------",df6.year.iloc[i], "-----------------")
    j=i
    if(j<df6.year.count()-1):
        while(df6.year.iloc[j + 1] - df6.year.iloc[j]==1):
            end_year = df6.year.iloc[j + 1]
            counter += 1
            j += 1
            #print("While loop",end_year, i, j, counter)
    if(counter==0 and pd.isnull(df6.at[i,'year_max'])):
        df6.year_max.iloc[i] = end_year
        df6.year_min.iloc[i] = start_year
    elif(counter!=0):
        for idx in range(counter + 1):
            df6.year_max.iloc[idx + i] = end_year
            df6.year_min.iloc[idx + i] = start_year
            #print(counter+1, start_year, end_year)
```

Comment: Hi @acehomie. It would be nice if you included a little explanation in your answer about what you fixed. Right now, somebody trying to learn from this answer is forced to do some kind of code comparison between question and answer. Thanks in advance.